# NLTK does not find path even though I downloaded the directory to the path list of nltk.data.path

Tags: python, installation, nltk

When running `nltk.data.path` I get the following directories:

`nltk.data.path`

```
['/home/alex/nltk_data',
 '/home/alex/miniconda3/envs/machinelearning/nltk_data',
 '/home/alex/miniconda3/envs/machinelearning/share/nltk_data',
 '/home/alex/miniconda3/envs/machinelearning/lib/nltk_data',
 '/usr/share/nltk_data',
 '/usr/local/share/nltk_data',
 '/usr/lib/nltk_data',
 '/usr/local/lib/nltk_data']
```

Ok great now I want to download NLTK `stopwords` data.

```
nltk.download('stopwords',download_dir='/home/alex/miniconda3/envs/machinelearning/nltk_data')
```

Everything works fine but when I call `stopwords` an OS error throws in:

```
stopwords.words('english')[0:15]

OSError: No such file or directory: '/home/alex/nltk_data/corpora/stopwords/english'
```

Well I thought NLTK look into the whole list of paths. But essentially what this error suggests is that it's looking only into `'/home/alex/nltk_data'` not finding the data and throwing an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting up environment variable `NLTK_DATA` to the directory where you stored the NLTK's data. [By default](http://www.nltk.org/data.html) installation directory is `nltk_data` in your home directory.

You can either set it by:

```
NLTK_DATA='/home/alex/miniconda3/envs/machinelearning/nltk_data'
```

or use the default `/home/alex/nltk_data` directory (move the data there / symlink there).

The `download_dir` parameter is only instructing where to store the data *temporarily*.